# i have tried many time using for loop but till now i didnt get correct ans so kaindly help to saltout

Tags: python

Ask the user to enter a number x. Use the sep optional argument to print out x, 2x, 3x, 4x, and 5x, each separated by three dashes, like below.

Enter a number: 7
7---14---21---28---35

Comment: Hello! welcome to SO, Pls see this link on how to ask a proper question that will help SO community to help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. You do need to provide what you've tried so far for this problem.

Comment: I agree with @Anil_M. I also strongly suggest reviewing this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably running into issues because input() returns a string, not an integer.

Try this:

```
num = int(input("Choose a number" + "\n"))
output = num
max = 6

for i in range(2, max):
    output = str(output) + "---" + str(num * i)

print(output)
```

Comment: i think u didnt use separator  optional argument. so kindly try to use sep optional arument  i want ans like using sep.here is one simple ex:- print ('The value of 3+4 is ', 3+4, '.', sep='')

Answer (score 1):

```
def func(param=0):
print(str(param )+ '---'+str(2*param)+'---'+str(3*param)+'---'+str(4*param)+'---'+str(5*param))

n = int(input("Enter a number"))
func(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this list comprehension

```
a=int(input())
print("---".join([str((e+1)*a) for e in range(5)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def fun():
    # Defining default separator 
    sep = "---"  

    # Asking user to enter number
    x = input("Enter the number: ")

    # Asking user for 
    new_sep = raw_input('Would you like to provide a separator? If yes, please specify. If not, leave blank and press "return key":')

    if new_sep:
        sep = new_sep
    return sep.join(map(str, [x*n for n in range(1,6)]))
```

**Using default separator**

```
fun()
Enter the number: 7
Would you like to provide a separator? If yes, please specify. If not, leave blank and press "return key":
'7---14---21---28---35'
```

**User specifying separator**

```
fun()
Enter the number: 7
Would you like to provide a separator? If yes, please specify. If not, leave blank and press "return key": ***
'7***14***21***28***35'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use the `sep` parameter of `print`

```
x=eval(input("Enter a number: "))
print(x,2*x,3*x,4*x,5*x, sep='---')
```

Output:

```
Enter a number:7
7---14----21---28---35
```

Comment: It is quite a late answer, but at least you are answering exactly OP's question. Anyway you should mind formatting, case and avoid *code only answers*. I have fixed those little problems for you here.

Comment: Is `eval` the right thing to use here? I feel like either `float` or `int` should be used as clearly a number is expected from user input.